# Using PHP to write to a text file, unable to see human error

Tags: php, html, forms

I've looked around the site extensively and even though I feel like I know what I'm doing; I must be mistaken as I can't seem to find my error.

```
<?php
if $myfile = fopen("submits/mydata.txt", "w")

(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['ign']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['op16-18']) && isset($_POST['op19-24']) && isset($_POST['op25+']) && isset($_POST['role'])) {
    $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['ign'] . '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['op16-18'] . '-' . $_POST['op19-24'] . '-' . $_POST['op25+'] . '-' . $_POST['role']  "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('submits/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if ($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    } else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
} else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

The above is the html being used and the below is the form: html

```
<form action="" method="">
<?php include 'form.php' ;?>
<label class=""><b></b> </label><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<label>Real name</label><br>
<input name="name" class="input-box" type="text" name="firstname"  placeholder="Name"><br><br><br>
<label>Game name</label><br>
<input name="ign"class="input-box" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Alias"><br><br><br>

<label> Email </label>
<br><input name="email" class="input-box form-email" type="email" name="comment" placeholder="OPTIONAL"><br><br><br><br>
<label class="">Age:</label><br><br>

<span class="radio-age">
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
<input name="op16-18" type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector">
<label for="f-option">16-18</label>
<div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li>
<input name="op19-24" type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector">
<label for="s-option">19-24</label>
<div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
</li>
<li>
<input  name="op25+" type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector">
<label for="t-option">25+</label>  
<div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</span>
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="select-span">Tier Select</span><br>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <select name="tier">
            <option value="bronze"> Bronze </option>
            <option value="silver"> Silver </option>
            <option value="gold"> Gold </option>
            <option value="platinum"> Platinum </option>
            <option value="diamond"> Diamond </option>
            <option value="master"> Master </option>
            <option value="grandmaster"> Grandmaster </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="select-span">Role Select</span><br>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <select name="role">
            <option value="bronze"> Healer </option>
            <option value="silver"> Tank </option>
            <option value="gold"> Damage </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input class="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"   value="Submit">
</form>
```

I felt it was inefficient to remove the contents, if anyone could spot my formatting error or complete misuse of functions. I would really appreciate the wise words.

Comment: Oy, too many to count. Use an IDE that will show your errors.

Comment: Could you elaborate @aynber ?

Comment: You're missing a `(` and `&&`  anad a `)` and a `.`

Comment: I appreciate the comment but I can't see where? @AbraCadaver

Comment: I formatted the php you posted. you have a few syntax errors. The way you've structure the if statement is incorrect and confusing to look at as well.

Comment: Actually, by moving the if, I count 3: move the `if` to before the isset. Unless you're $myfile is supposed to be used as part of the if, but it's never used again. When you move the if, there's no semi-colon at the end. There's no concatenation period before `"\n"`. As I said, get a proper IDE that shows errors and can format your code properly, and it will help a lot.

Comment: A `div` in a `span`? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

that's a start. Just like notepadd++ and w3school is a start.

```
if (

  ($myfile = fopen("submits/mydata.txt", "w")) &&
  isset($_POST['name']) && 
  isset($_POST['ign']) && 
  isset($_POST['email']) && 
  isset($_POST['op16-18']) && 
  isset($_POST['op19-24']) && 
  isset($_POST['op25+']) && 
  isset($_POST['role'])
  ) {

    $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['ign'] . '-' . $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['op16-18'] . '-' . $_POST['op19-24'] . '-' . $_POST['op25+'] . '-' . $_POST['role'].  "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('submits/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if ($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    } else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }

  /*
   * 
   */
} else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Netbeans says it's ok, (no formating error) did my part